# How to use "contains" in antMatchers?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using spring security in a ZUUL application, my API controls all access to my microservices. Using a filter can allow specif routes per login, in the filter inside i have the object HttpSecurity who makes the control through the method ".antMatchers".

For example:

```
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/**/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/csrf/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/v2/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/signin/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/microservice/chatws/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/microservice/*swagger*").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/**/microservice/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/microservice/v2/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/microservice/webjars/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**/microservice/csrf/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();

        http.apply(new JwtTokenFilterConfigurer(jwtTokenProvider));
    }
```

I want to allow all routes who has "swagger" in any locale, in the begging, middle or end. I was thinking in something like method contains of String class, if contains "swagger" so permitAll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes can always implement your own matching logic by implementing `RequestMatcher`. The following example shows matching the request URI (without query parameter) containing the word "swagger" :

```
http.authorizeRequests()
       .requestMatchers(req-> req.getRequestURI().contains("swagger")).permitAll()
```